# A little clarification about asymptotic directions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

How do I compute [asymptotic directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Asymptotes)? In my book, it says that we write:

$$f=f_0+f_1 + \dots + f_d$$

Where each $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$ and $d\neq 0$ and then, each asymptotic direction is a component $ax+by$ of $f_d$.

So for example, suppose I have $f=x^2 y^2+x^2+x y^3+x y^2+x+y-1$ then we have $f_4=x^2y^2 + xy^3$ do I just need to factor $f_4$ as $y^2 x(x+y)$ and hence, the asymptotic directions are $(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Try [graphing it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eu6wcovg18) to see!

Comment: @KReiser I plotted the [asymptotic directions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/syg5afycin). I'm a bit confused with the following: Shouldn't each one point to a direction where the graph goes to infinity? For example, this happens in the case [$xy-1$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bthkiutfmm).

Comment: Two things are happening: one is that when you have an asymptotic direction $ax+by$, you want to consider the line cut out by $ax+by=0$, not the point $(a,b)$. The other is that the asymptotic direction corresponding to $y$ is imaginary and therefore isn't seen by the real graph: you can check that points of the form $(x,\pm i)$ are approximate solutions of your function as $x\to\infty$ (divide through by $x^2$, plug in, etc). I forgot to check the second thing while typing my comment earlier.